# Not require FactoryBot preface before create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I am using `FactoryBot` in my `seeds.rb` to populate my database. I have to call `FactoryBot.` before I call `build` or `create`. Is there a way I can not have to do that? Also, should I even be using `FactoryBot` for seeding, or is it just for testing?

Note: FactoryBot was previously called FactoryGirl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Including [`FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/FactoryBot/Syntax/Methods) into your seeds.rb file will allow you to call `build` or `create` without the `FactoryBot` prefix:

```ruby
include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
```

As to whether it's a good idea, I can see how it's an appealing option but it seems to me that you'd be maintaining factories for two completely different purposes.  Keeping them in sync as your application changes, or separating your test factories from your seed factories, seems problematic to me.

Note: FactoryBot was previously called FactoryGirl